# Groovy - Encoding issue parsing Korean in XML

Tags: xml, encoding, utf-8, groovy

I have an XML file which is UTF-8 encoded (both XMLSpy and NotePad++ show this as the encoding). The file contains Korean strings which all display fine in both editors.

```
<Table>
    <Column ss:StyleID="s63" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="290.25"/>
    <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
        <Cell>
            <Data ss:Type="String">왕복</Data>
        </Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
        <Cell>
            <Data ss:Type="String">..에서</Data>
        </Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
        <Cell>
            <Data ss:Type="String">편도</Data>
        </Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
        <Cell>
            <Data ss:Type="String">기내</Data>
        </Cell>
    </Row>
</Table>
```

I'm using Groovy to parse the XML file and write the contents out to a new XML file.

```
        XmlParser parser = new XmlParser();
        def inputSource = new InputSource(new FileReader(file));
        inputSource.setEncoding('UTF-8');

        def workbook = parser.parse(inputSource);
```

I then write this out to a new XML file, specifying UTF-8 even though I don't think this should be needed.

```
        def finalFileWriter = new FileWriter(new File(file.getName()+"_clean.xml").asWritable('UTF-8'));
        def printer = new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(finalFileWriter));
        printer.preserveWhitespace = true;
        printer.print(workbook);
```

The resulting XML file, according to XMLSpy, contains characters that should not be present in a file using UTF-8 and therefore get replaced with rubbish. They are also displayed incorrectly in Notepad++. Both editors say the new file is UTF-8 encoded.

The above code works perfectly fine when operating on 3 other files of identicle structure, which are for Simplified Chinese, Traditional Chinese and Japanese. Any guidance at all would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have some example input?

Comment: Thanks for putting the XML into the original post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work for me if I put your input XML into `/tmp/input.xml`:

```
def workbook = new XmlParser(false, false).parse( '/tmp/input.xml' )

new File( '/tmp/test.xml' ).withWriter( 'UTF-8' ) { w ->
    new XmlNodePrinter( new PrintWriter( w ) ).with { p ->
        preserveWhitespace = true
        p.print( workbook )
    }
}
```

I have to tell the parser to ignore namespaces as you don't specify what the `ss:` namespace is.

But the output in `/tmp/test.xml` seems right?

Comment: I'll give this a go Tim and post back. Thanks for looking into this, regardless of the outcome

Comment: Cool, fingers crossed :-)

Comment: Tim... you're pretty great :D Works well, thanks a lot. So more importantly, why? :) Do you know why your way parsing the file and printing it work but mines runs into character issues? I'll take a look at the groovy API to see what it says about withWriter() and PrintWriter() as they are the differences between our two approaches (plus you used a different XMLParser constructor to me). I'm more a Groovy hacker than coder so still need to do a lot more reading.

Comment: @Shigsy It's probably getting lost by the `InputSource` or the `FileReader` in your code.  My guess would be the `FileReader`, to test this hypothesis, replace `def inputSource = new InputSource(new FileReader(file))` with `def inputSource = new InputSource(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8")))` and see if your original code works.  As you can see though, the Groovy way is noticably shorter and more readable ;-)

Comment: @Shigsy As for the different constructor, I needed that as there were no namespace definitions in the xml example you provided.  You have more complete xml, so might be able to get away with just `new XmlParser()` as you originally had it :-)

Comment: Great, I'll give that a go, just to see. Thanks again for the solution; I can't upvote as my reputation is too low (new account) but I've marked your answer as correct.

Comment: @Shigsy It's always worth finding out, just to set your mind at ease sometimes ;-)  No worries, and thanks!  Glad I could help!